# Problematoc with c++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I wrote many derived classes that obviously calls, at instantiation, previous constructors first...

One of these constructors implements a call to a virtual function called AtCreate()...

Not a good idea...

When I try to derive that class... other constructors are not yet called and AtCreate() is already called...

If I always use std::new to obtain an object, I can be sure that I will have control over that object... after ALL constructors have been called... Simply by overloading the global new operator... and so able to call a virtual function of mine like virtual void AtCreate()

But...

If I use local objects, within local stack, and no more pointers, how can I automatically call that AtCreate() function AFTER all constructors have been called .. ?

What Im trying to achieve is a AfterConstruction/BeforDestruction strategy...

I was quiet sure that using a thread and a pool would help, but how to know when all constructors are called as they will be added to the pool in a basic class's constructor... ?

```
Class basic 
{ basic() { this> AtCreate(); } 

  virtual void AtCreate() = 0; 
}

Class A  :  basic 
{ A()  :  basic() {}

  void AtCreate() {...}
}

Class B  :  A 
{ B()  :  A {}

  void AtCreate() {...}
}
```

In this example allocating B or A will call AtCreate BEFORE A or B constructor...

Comment: Please show the code instead of describing it. Make sure it is _minimal_, as in it contains only as much as needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: When an object is being created the base class is created first then the 1st derived class then the 2nd etc.  The mean that when a base class is being created any derived classes __do not yet exist__.  (note: the above does not apply for virtual inheritance - but don't go there).

Comment: Thanks for stopping me about virtual classes... i revised the question and included a sample and a reference to use a thread.... Any idea  ?

Comment: In the code the at the line `basic() { this> AtCreate();` `Class A` does not yet exist and the vtable pointer (implementation detail) still point to `Class basic`.

Comment: I truely understand that...but how to solve it when allocating local variables in the stack... I can solve it when using pointers by overloading the global new operator...

Comment: I suspect anything that works when globally overloading `operator new` is going to involve Undefined Behaviour as the creation of objects from base to derived is fundamental.  Please post the working code, to see if we can suggest how to change it for use with automatic variables.

Comment: The working code is not richer than the pseudo code above as it is not working...

Comment: The idea of "fixing" an incorrect design by overriding global new or using a thread pool is the kind of lateral outside the box thinking we like to see here at Tragedy Inc.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer here is to make "factory" methods (aka "builders" or "named constructors")

```
class basic 
{ 
protected:
    basic() { } 
    virtual void AtCreate() = 0; 
public:
    virtual ~basic() { }  //if you have virtual methods, always have virtual destructor
    
    //value factory method
    template<class derived, class...Ts>
    static derived create_value(Ts&&...vs) {
         derived item(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
         item.AtCreate();
         return item;
    }
    //unique_ptr factory method
    template<class derived, class...Ts>
    static std::unique_ptr<derived> create_unique(Ts&&...vs) {
         std::unique_ptr<derived> item = std::make_unique<derived>(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
         item->AtCreate();
         return item;
    }
    //shared_ptr factory method
    template<class derived, class...Ts>
    static std::shared_ptr<derived> create_shared(Ts&&...vs) {
         std::shared_ptr<derived> item = std::make_shared<derived>(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
         item->AtCreate();
         return item;
    }
};
```

Also make sure that all non-copy/move constructors of all derived classes are `private`. Since the constructors are `private`, other code can't construct them directly. The only way to construct an instance is through the factory methods, which always call `AtCreate`:

```
void function() {
    std::shared_ptr<basic> shared = basic::create_shared<A>();
    std::unique_ptr<basic> unique = basic::create_unique<B>();
    C value = basic::create_value<C>();
}
```

Comment: Thats the nearest correct answer I could accept, but that does not resolve my problem since I will have to check all my local variables and also the heap allocatef and adapt it...

Comment: @blueperfect: you don't have to "check" your variables. Since `A`, `B`, and `C` should have `protected` non-copy constructors, then all local variables not using the factory method will fail to compile.

Comment: I understand but that doesnt really solve my problem... I NEED to instanciate objects and, after instanciation is done (the whole !), I NEED to call a virtual method... Just like the tricky VCL AfterConstruction mechanism... but without VCL...without templating and using std::...

Comment: @blueperfect: The factory methods I describe here allow anyone to instantiate objects.  If you NEED to not have factory methods, then every caller needs to remember to call the virtual method themselves, and there is no magic workaround.

Comment: I agree with you when the standard c++ pattern rules.. There it is special : I have to use CBuilder 5 but should be portable to MsDos 16bits..under 3.1 !!! Let's say a console application... So I try to use only standard C libraries, surrounded by simple C++ classes.. My conclusion, for now, is to write all classes targeting a main class that will then nerver be derived...but used as an Atom of my object's application... Now, every Atom could be overriden by a sort of factory class that will manipulate all Atoms (adding properties, creation, idle...)... on its way... I'll let you know

Comment: modern C++ has no problem porting to MSDos 16 bits under 3.1. CBuilder 5 might have problems, but not c++ itself. I don't know what you mean by an atom class. do you mean a singleton? it sounds like you are afraid of theoretical problems, and so are coding weird, and the weird code is causing actual problems. weird code usually runs slower and uses more memory. just write simple, straightforward code. it will run faster, and use less memory.

Comment: youre not so wrong, but I explain it : what I am trying to achieve is a far in time (20years) project that uses its own set of classes...and very little c++ functinalities... See it as a simple Turbo Pascal Program ported to C++, but now evolving to a Graphical Interface... So I will not use the std::vector or or=ther std.... Anyway I am still looking for a polish way to obtain a correct result...

Comment: When I say it migrates to Graphical User Interface, consider that the classes are done and built to produce arrays of structs organized as bitmaps of text pixels... I can also handle rgb structs and reverse it to HBitmap or HDC, but I dont want to deal deeper with the WinAPI... The goal is to reproduce text maps to whatever the display is... Actually, I do use MsDos 1x1 font to obtain a Pixel Text render...on a console

Comment: But that is only what it has to do... My question is really how to know in standard C++ that a constructor call is totally achieved...so that I can call the first virtual function efficiently)... Even on local objects allocated on the stack... (this last point is the difficulty I meet)

Comment: @blueperfect: My answer shows you how to do that already.  `B value = basic::create_value<B>();`